# Add data to sqlite database only onetime and read multiple times

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm new to the `sqlite`. In my android project, I have a database which I need to add those data only onetime to the app.(do not insert data everytime, when app runs). How can I achieve this task?

I tried with creating

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

}
```

and call this class in `onCreate` method in `MainActivity`

Comment: show me your code what you tried till now?

Comment: Just insert the data in onCreate of the DatabaseHelper

Comment: Simply create database using firefox sqlite manager and put that on assets and move from sdcard and access every time. this is the best way.

Answer (score 5):

in SQLiteOpenHelper there is a method that called once and just once ever, it's the **onCreate** method. so if you need to add datas to DB only one time you have to do it inside this method.

But if for some reason you want to add more datas to the DB you could do it in **onUpgrade** method this time.

take this simple example:

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

  private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "dbName";
  private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

  private static final String TABLE_NAME = "tableName";

  public MySQLiteHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
  }

  //this function called only once ever in the life of the app
  @Override
  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    //Create database query
    database.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME + " (column1 type, columun2 type...); ");

    //Insert query
    database.execSQL("insert into " + TABLE_NAME + " values(value1,value2...);");
    database.execSQL("insert into " + TABLE_NAME + " values(value1,value2...);");
    database.execSQL("insert into " + TABLE_NAME + " values(value1,value2...);");
    database.execSQL("insert into " + TABLE_NAME + " values(value1,value2...);");
  }

  @Override
  public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    //add more insert query if you need to add more datas after, but you have first to upgrade your DATABASE_VERSION to a higher number
  }

}
```

Comment: How can I call this onCreate method from other class. I wouldn't implicitly call when creating instance from DatabaseHandler