# How to insert data into sqlite database just one time

Tags: android, sqlite

I need to add data to a  sqlite database just one time.That is I want users of my app see that data as perloaded.How to do that.
I performed it using  the query

**INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME VALUES (value1,value2,value3,...valueN);**

But each time app opens that page it,again and again add the products..Please help

**code**

```
public class product_display extends Activity {

SQLiteDatabase mydb;
ListView prd_list;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.product_dispay);
    prd_list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

     Intent in=getIntent();
     Bundle bundle=in.getExtras();
     final String list=bundle.getString("key");


  mydb = product_display.this.openOrCreateDatabase("products", MODE_PRIVATE, null); 
  mydb.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS product(pimage BLOB,pid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,pname TEXT,pprice NUMERIC,pspec TEXT,pfeature TEXT)");   
  mydb.execSQL("INSERT INTO product(pname,pprice,pspec) VALUES('Candle stick 3',4000,'Solar garden / pathway light,Solar Panel:1pc crystal silicon solar cell,Material:Stainless steel ,WaterProof and safe ')");

    Cursor cr = mydb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM product", null);
    final String[] pname = new String[cr.getCount()];
    String[] price = new String[cr.getCount()];

    int i = 0;
    while(cr.moveToNext())
    {
        String name = cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex("pname"));
        String prprice = cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex("pprice"));
        pname[i] = name;
        price[i] = prprice;
        i++;
    }

    ListAdapter adapter = new ListAdapter(this, pname, price);
    prd_list.setAdapter(adapter);

    prd_list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String nme = pname[arg2];   
            Bundle bun = new Bundle();
            bun.putString("key",list);
            Bundle bn = new Bundle();
            bn.putString("name",nme);
            Intent in = new Intent(product_display.this,Product_Details.class);
            in.putExtras(bun);
            in.putExtras(bn);
            startActivity(in);
            }
    });



}

}
```

Comment: make column  Unique while creating table..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15061653/run-a-piece-of-code-only-once-when-an-application-is-installed

Comment: **INSERT** will always insert new items even if already existing. **UPDATE** will change existing rows. Or you can **check if existing** before inserting.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23085040/add-data-to-sqlite-database-only-onetime-and-read-multiple-times

Comment: @Duggu I added the part of my code to inserts data where you wrote one time data,.But it is not even inserting data for first time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try Like this:

```
public class TestDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public TestDatabaseHelper(Context context, String name,
            CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Create Your tables here
        //and insert the pre loaded records here

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Comment: OK..But I dont have any idea about SQLiteOpenHelper. Can you please tell where should I add this part of code.? Or should I make new java page?

Comment: go through following link http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sqlite_database.htm

Comment: //and insert the pre loaded records here == How to get the database itself here ?

Answer (score 1):

It's simple just create a static variable count and initialize it to 0. And increment counter to 1 after first insertion and also checks if counter is 0 before insertion. So in Your Case :

```
static int count = 0;

if(count == 0){
    mydb.execSQL("INSERT INTO product(pname,pprice,pspec) VALUES('Candle stick 3',4000,'Solar garden / pathway light,Solar Panel:1pc crystal silicon solar cell,Material:Stainless steel ,WaterProof and safe ')");
    count++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using `SQLiteOpenHelper` to manage your database, put the inserts in the helper `onCreate()` callback. It gets invoked exactly once when the database file is created for the first time. Just remember to call the database methods on the `SQLiteDatabase` passed in as a parameter.

Comment: No.I am not using SQLiteOpenHelper.I have posted my code.I have no idea about SQLiteOpenHelper.

Comment: Seriously consider using `SQLiteOpenHelper` to manage your database lifecycle.

Comment: Okay.Let me Look into SQLiteOpenHelper.But now,How can I implement SQLiteOpenHelper in my code?

Answer (score 0):

you must check with a cycle "if" that is not already inserted that value in the database. I would do:
1) select fields from table
2)

```
if (field1 != value) then
       execute(INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME VALUES(value1,value2,value3,...valueN));

else{

 // continues with the program
}
```

3) close the connection

P.S. sorry for my bad english(I'm italian)

Answer (score 0):

Use sharedprefrence to check if data has been submitted before. Another workaround may be make a new table in sqlite and use that table to check if data have been inserted before. 
Eg. New table be check_insertion. With column id and user_id.
Now check if in this table there is any entry if not then you may run your query which you want to be ran first time only.