# Inserting rows into table only once in Android Database

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I want to only insert like 10 rows into a table at database creation. I do not want them added every time the app is open. Just once as a table with final values. How would I go about doing this? Thanks!

```
public void insertEvents(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COL_EVENT, "value1");
    values.put(COL_EVENT, "value2");
    values.put(COL_EVENT, "value3");
    values.put(COL_EVENT, "value4");

    db.insert(TABLE_EVENTS, null, values);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do it in `onCreate` method of [DatabaseHelper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html)

EDIT: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28025002/how-to-insert-data-into-sqlite-database-just-one-time) is the similar question. Or you can try [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sqlite_database.htm)

Comment: Try to be more elaborative. Share similar answers.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using `SQLiteOpenHelper`, put the inserts in its `onCreate()`. Use the `SQLiteDatabase` passed in as argument, do not recursively call `getWritableDatabase()`.

Comment: Got it, when I called getWritableDatabase() before I would get recursive error since I was calling it in the main activity as well

Answer (score 0):

I know this might be too late but I'm just sharing my answers. Your code seems to show that you are trying to add 4 rows. Here are some pointers:

1) Do it in the `onCreate` method, as mentioned by **@Georgiy Shur**.

2) The `insert` method only inserts **one** row at a time. So you should do this instead:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(COL_EVENT, "value1");
db.insert(TABLE_EVENTS, null, values);
values.put(COL_EVENT, "value2");
db.insert(TABLE_EVENTS, null, values);
values.put(COL_EVENT, "value3");
db.insert(TABLE_EVENTS, null, values);
values.put(COL_EVENT, "value4");
db.insert(TABLE_EVENTS, null, values);
```